# Import works in script but not in nosetests

Tags: python, python-import, nosetests

I've seen a few similar questions but still can't get my test to work.
My file structure looks like this:

```
/my-project
    /tests
        test_my_project.py
    /my_project
        my_project.py
        config.py
```

In `my_project.py` I have `import config` and it works well. But when I run nosetests I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

In `test_my_project.py` I use `from my_project import my_project`.

What's the cause of this error?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in `/my_project`? If not, add one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Like I said below another answer adding `__init__.py` didn't help. Changing `import config` to `from my_project import config` makes it work in nosetests but fail when I run script. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Is your project actually *installed* for the interpreter you're using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel stupid but I don't really know what you mean by _installing project_. I'm sorry but I'm new in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [python packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). 
You actually want to be the directory /my_project to be a package directory. Hence you should place an `__init__.py` file in this directory. It suffices that the file is empty.
However, when you want to use your package frome elsewhere, it makes sense to put an `from my_project import *` into `__init__.py`.

Comment: `__init__.py` didn't change anything. Still the same error. I noticed that when I change import in `my_project.py` to `from my_project import config` it works in nosetests but not when I run script.